# How to make WiFi work for toshiba C850...?

Tags: wifi, driver, dsl, ethernet

I have a toshiba laptop c850, dual core. Toshiba does not provide any driver for Wi-Fi for Ubuntu 12.10. I am currently having problem in using DSL modem, Ethernet and Wi-Fi. Can anyone tell me the solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you please post the wlan chipset? Try `lspci -v` in a terminal and post the output.

Comment: is this you asked....?

Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
 Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device ff1e
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
 Memory at 88500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
 I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
 Capabilities: <access denied>

Comment: I made an answer with the information you provided, but this is only for the Ethernet controller. Your question states that you have problems with your WiFi controller too, I can try my best but I need the chipset of your WiFi card.

Comment: it is not showing but look at this...

Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
 Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
 Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast

Comment: >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
 Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
 I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
 Memory behind bridge: 88500000-885fffff
 Secondary status: 66MHz- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- <SERR- <PERR-
 BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
  PriDiscTmr- SecDiscTmr- DiscTmrStat- DiscTmrSERREn-
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport
 Kernel modules: shpchp

Comment: this is all my system shared

Answer (score 0):

maybe you will find some information there :

http://www.linlap.com/toshiba_satellite_c850-c855

> Wireless
>
> A really up to date kernel is required for wireless support, at least
>   3.5.0 is recommended. Realtek has the Linux drivers available for download but they must be re-complied after upgrades to kernel.

Answer (score 0):

As you commented, you got the Atheros Communications Inc. AR8162 Fast Ethernet Controller.
This is some guesswork here because there are several versions of the driver and some people state only one is working for them, I stick with the most popular for now.

First download this file from another machine: 
https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/28/compat-drivers-2013-03-28-5-u.tar.bz2

If you have Ubuntu or another Linux distro on your second machine you can use `wget` to download the file:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/28/compat-drivers-2013-03-28-5-u.tar.bz2
```

Next, use your preferred method (preferably an USB Drive) to copy it to your target machine (Toshiba C850) and use the following commands in a terminal. Make sure you are in the right directory first and use `cd` to change to the directory where your downloaded file resides.

```
tar -xzvf compat-drivers-2013-03-28-5-u.tar.bz2
cd compat-drivers-2013-03-28-5-u
./scripts/driver-select alx 
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe alx
```

If this doesn't work try a reboot first then you can try one of the other versions, I can't tell which will work for you:

- http://wireless.kernel.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2012-02-28-p.tar.bz2
- https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/04/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2

Sources (for further reading): [This question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205582/how-do-i-get-an-atheros-ar8162-working) and [this thread in the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139394).